# How to create string resource for same language but different region?

Tags: android, android-studio, locale

While creating a new resource file with **Locale** qualifier inside *res/values* folder, I have chosen **English** as **Language** and **US:United States** as **Region** then directory name is automatically created as **values-en-rUS**. And file created successfully having above language and region. As you can see in the pic.

[image]

But now I want to create another file having **English** as **Language** and **GB:United Kingdom** as **Region** then directory name is automatically created as **values-en-rGB**. but when I click OK button, it does not allow to create file for same language having different region. See below pic.

[image]

My requirement is to create different string resource for different region. Two different region might have same language. So how can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution. Don't let android studio to generate resource directory name by selecting **Language** and **Region** from the populated dialog, instead type directory name for each region though language remains same.For instance type **values-en-rUS** in place of directory name to create resource file.Here **en** stands for **English** language and **r** stands for **Region** and **US** is the country code for **United States**. Same applicable for **values-en-rGB**.Now I am able to create resource file for different region having same language.